# Google Chart: add vertical line on every monday

Tags: javascript, graph, google-visualization

I need to add one vertical line on google chart marking monday. as shown in picture.
[image]

all of other things has been done.. but couldn't figure out how to put vertical line marking every monday. 
I found this

```
hAxis: {
            ticks: ""
        },
```

functionality in google chart use i can make user of.. but couldn't figure out how do i use it for every monday....

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this.  In order to use `hAxis.ticks`, your domain column (x-axis) must be type "date"; using it will show tick marks and labels *only* on the dates you specify (so in your example, you would lose the "Aug 13", "Aug 15", and "Aug 17" labels in between "Aug 11" and "Aug 18").  You can also use domain axis annotations to add labeled vertical lines to your chart, which might be a better fit if you are looking to get a close duplicate of the image.

Answer (score 5):

Use This in data:

```
 data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
```

And this in options:

```
annotations: {
        style: 'line'
    }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/NC37X/